# Last few tasks of Spark hang and progress extremely slowly

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, pyspark, thread-dump

My spark job reads from and writes to a S3 bucket, the problem I had lately is that last few tasks of a job just hang there, no error thrown, just progress very very slowly.
[image]

[image]

e.g. these last 7 tasks take increasingly long time to finish, you can see **Median** is 28s, but **Max** for last few tasks can be high as 40 mins. I'm pretty sure data is not skewed, each partition contains only ~100Mb data, but still takes 40 mins to finish as shown in below screenshot.
[image]

My question is what could be potential causes for this problem? Could this because of S3 connection etc., because we used to run spark jobs on NFS and didn't have such issue before. I have tried almost all configurations I can possibly find to help resolve this issue, but still no luck :(

This is a copy of thread dump of one of those "hanging" executors:

```
java.base@11.0.10/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.base@11.0.10/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
java.base@11.0.10/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
java.base@11.0.10/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
app//com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
app//com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.read(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:197)
app//com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:176)
app//com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135)
app//com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
app//com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:180)
app//com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
app//com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
app//com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
app//com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:180)
app//com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
app//com.amazonaws.util.LengthCheckInputStream.read(LengthCheckInputStream.java:107)
app//com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
app//com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3AbortableInputStream.read(S3AbortableInputStream.java:125)
app//com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
app//org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.lambda$read$3(S3AInputStream.java:468)
app//org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream$$Lambda$1124/0x00007f862e16fd08.execute(Unknown Source)
app//org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:109)
app//org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.lambda$retry$3(Invoker.java:265)
app//org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker$$Lambda$954/0x00007f86647c4900.execute(Unknown Source)
app//org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:322)
app//org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:261)
app//org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:236)
app//org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.read(S3AInputStream.java:464) => holding Monitor(org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream@1670038891})
java.base@11.0.10/java.io.DataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
app//org.apache.parquet.io.DelegatingSeekableInputStream.readFully(DelegatingSeekableInputStream.java:102)
app//org.apache.parquet.io.DelegatingSeekableInputStream.readFullyHeapBuffer(DelegatingSeekableInputStream.java:127)
app//org.apache.parquet.io.DelegatingSeekableInputStream.readFully(DelegatingSeekableInputStream.java:91)
app//org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$ConsecutiveChunkList.readAll(ParquetFileReader.java:1174)
app//org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readNextRowGroup(ParquetFileReader.java:805)
app//org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.checkEndOfRowGroup(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:313)
app//org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:268)
app//org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:174)
app//org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
app//org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
app//org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:173)
app//org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
app//scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
app//scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
app//scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
app//org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.write(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:177)
app//org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
app//org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
app//org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
app//org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
app//org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
app//org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$Lambda$650/0x00007f86653e2440.apply(Unknown Source)
app//org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
app//org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.base@11.0.10/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: what's code are you running? you mentioned data is not skewed. How did you verify that?

Comment: You need to provide code that you are running. Mostly the situation that you are describing happens due to data skew. Are you doing any joins after reading the data and before saving the data? You can check the event Timeline option in the Spark UI for the Specific stage and it will give you an idea whether data is skewed or not.